# Overriding the default Content-Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Rails API which accepts only JSON as input.  If I fail to include a header of Content-Type: application/json, then `request.headers['Content-Type']` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the params do not get parsed properly.  The whole json body becomes a key in the params.  The result is a 422, which is confusing to API users.

**How can I change this to default to parsing as json if no Content-Type header is supplied?**

Lots of other questions answer how to do this with the response format.  To change this default, you can specify it in the controller with:

```
 request.format = :json
```

Or in a route namespace with something like:

```
 namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
```

This, however, changes the default response format and does not change the default request format.  **What I need to do is to change the default request format for parsing parameters.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my admittedly *terrible* solution derived from the suggestion in Micael Nussbaumer's answer.  I'd love it if some Rubyists could magically turn this ugly hack into a pithy one liner.

```
module Api
  class BaseApiController < ActionController::API

  private
    # This is an ugly hack needed to make it default to json if you do not
    # specify a Content-Type.  If you see this and know of a better way please
    # say so!
    def params
      if !@params
        if request.headers["Content-Type"]=="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          body_string = request.body.read
          begin
            hash = JSON.parse(body_string)
            @params = ActionController::Parameters.new(hash)
          rescue
            # do nothing
          end
        end
        if !@params
          @params = super
        end
      end
      @params
    end

    ...

end
```

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it with middleware this way for Rails API (`rails new my_project --api`)

config:

```
# config/application.rb
# ...
require './lib/middleware/consider_all_request_json_middleware'
# ...

module MyApplication
    # ...
  class Application < Rails::Application
        # ...
        config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::Static,ConsiderAllRequestJsonMiddleware)
        # ...
```

middleware:

```
# lib/middleware/consider_all_request_json_middleware.rb
class ConsiderAllRequestJsonMiddleware
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["CONTENT_TYPE"] == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = 'application/json'
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

original: https://blog.eq8.eu/til/content-type-applicationjson-by-default-in-rails-5.html

Answer (score 2):

```
parsed = JSON.parse(json_body) unless request.headers["Content-Type"] == 'application/json'
```

Comment: The code shown will generate a hash, not a ActionController::Parameters instance needed for standard usage.  I can use the following variant to get what I want, but then I would have to paste it in every controller method because I cannot modify the default `params` from Rails.  `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(JSON.parse(request.body.read)) if request.headers["Content-Type"]=="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`  **There has got to be an easier way!**

Comment: Maybe insert some middleware on the rack prior to params parsing and correctly parse them if the headers are wrong? Maybe this can help you https://content.pivotal.io/blog/sanitizing-post-params-with-custom-rack-middleware (and perhaps there's an easier way, not sure, this seems straightforward though)

Comment: It seems that in Rails 5 a Rack middleware is no longer used to parse parameters, so the pivotal blog solution no longer works.  https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a1ced8b52ce60d0634e65aa36cb89f015f9f543d

Comment: @davidgyoung it seems so - which is unfortunate. Well you should be able to insert it into the rack prior to dispatching to routing (if you do `rake middleware` it will show you all the middleware start to finish), although I don't know how you can change the params object and have that change be kept while flying the request through the rack. But, at the same time, I think your users should definitively be passing the correct header to the request, because that's how the request should be formatted.

Comment: Yeah, I agree they *should* pass the header, but it's an easy mistake to make, so I'm trying to make it user friendly.  The current Rails default seems arbitrary and bad.  An alternative solution might be to send a custom error message in a JSON response telling the user to set ContentType: application/json